# How to replace image attribute in one JSON from another JSON?

Tags: python, json, replace, fetch

I am attempting to copy the image field from one group of json files and replace the image field in another group of JSON files.

JSON file structure that I am pulling from:

```json
[
    {
        "\ufeffFile Name": "16.png",
        "image": "https://arweave.net/v8OOGgKmlAZF56bpGQRv1nM691gu2FMlrNK3KY-3HZk"
    }
]
```

JSON file structure that I need to replace:

```json
{
  "name": "name",
  "symbol": "KK",
  "description": "description",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 1000,
  "image": "image.png",
  "external_url": "https://www.image.net",
  "edition": 16,
}
```

Code:

```py
import json
import os



def getFileImage(fp):
    with open(fp, 'r') as ff:
        try:
            return json.load(ff)['image']
        except:
            return None



def ReadAndReplace(filename, image):
    with open(filename, 'r') as ff:
        try:
            data = json.load(ff)
            data['image'] = image
            return json.dumps(data, indent = 4)
        except:
            print(f'Could not process file {filename}')
            return None



def Save(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as ff:
        ff.write(data)



def EnsureOutput():
    if not os.path.exists('output'):
        os.mkdir('output')

    if not os.path.exists('input') or not os.path.exists('toReplace'):
        print('Please create "input" and "toReplace" folders')
        exit()


def main():
    EnsureOutput()

    for i in os.listdir('toReplace'):
        filepath1 = os.path.join('input', i)
        filepath2 = os.path.join('toReplace', i)
        outpath = os.path.join('output', i)

    if os.path.exists(filepath1):
        image = getFileImage(filepath1)
        data = ReadAndReplace(filepath2, image)
        Save(outpath, data)
    else:
        print(f'No input file for toReplace "{i}" was found')



main()
```

When I run this code the image field updates to NULL instead of the link I need.

Comment: The JSON you are loading is an array not an object.

Comment: Unrelated note, `\ufeff` ([UTF-16 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16)) suggests to me that you're not reading the file correctly (or your data has been derived from previously-incorrectly-read data).

Comment: Is there a way to quickly make the array into an object? Also, the name field is not important in my replacing but would that cause an error?

Comment: If you know there is definitely one element in the list you can get the the first item within the list using `json.loads(ff)[0]`. But you should better check that using `len()`. Or use a loop if multiple items are possible, which is usually the case when using JSON arrays, otherwise there would be not point using them.

Comment: For a start, it usually helps to extract a [mcve]. It's also required for this kind of question. While at it, you will probably find that this has nothing to do with JSON, but with how you process data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The input you are loading is a JSON array and hence parsed as a python list, which you can obviously not access by keys as you are trying to do.
You first need to access the object within the array and then you may access this object with keys.

See the following:

```py
input = """
[
    {
        "\ufeffFile Name": "16.png",
        "image": "https://arweave.net/v8OOGgKmlAZF56bpGQRv1nM691gu2FMlrNK3KY-3HZk"
    }
]
"""

input_parsed = json.loads(input)
print(type(input_parsed))
print(input_parsed[0]["image"])
```

Expected output:

```
<class 'list'>
https://arweave.net/v8OOGgKmlAZF56bpGQRv1nM691gu2FMlrNK3KY-3HZk
```

For your `ReadAndReplace()` function this would look like this:

```py
def read_and_replace(filename, image):
    with open(filename, 'r') as ff:
        try:
            # data is a list
            data = json.load(ff)
            # be sure the list has actually one value exactly
            if len(data) == 1:
                data[0]['image'] = image
            return json.dumps(data, indent=4)
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, KeyError):
            print(f'Could not process file {filename}')
            return None
```

Comment: would I add this input in my code above the rest?? Sorry, as I am new to python coding and am not the most experienced in running automation!

Comment: Better to specify exceptions `except (json.JSONDecodeError, KeyError)`

Comment: I've added what you would need to do for your `ReadAndReplace()` function as an example. There are other points in your code where you need to make some adjustments though (you should be able to figure this out if you have understood the problem and the fix). On a unrelated note: You should make sure to follow Python conventions which suggest you should rename the function to `read_and_replace()`.
I've encompassed this into my code @OlvinRoght, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! Am attempting this now! Where else would I need to make adjustments?? I have been working on this almost all day lol!!

Comment: @ScotGarrison, consider spending another day reading [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), knowing language basics could significantly boost your productivity. This particular case nailed in [7.2.2. Saving structured data with json](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#saving-structured-data-with-json).

Comment: Use `data = json.loads(your_data)` first and then use `print(type(data))` to check what data types you are working with, if you can't see that from the JSON. Then go ahead and check out which data structures support which operations. Just google for `Python lists` and `Python dictionaries` and you will figure this out. Reading about JSON would also not go missing.